# Rails 5: API no implicit conversion of string into integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typeform

I'm trying to pass data from the Typeform Responses API. Everything is working except the user generated answers. Only one answer is working with `type: website` the other one `type: multiple_choice` for example isn't working.

An example response from Typeform looks like this:

```
"items": [
{
 "landing_id": XXXXXXX
},
"answers": [
        {
          "field": {
            "id": "hVONkQcnSNRj",
            "type": "website",
            "ref": "my_custom_website_reference"
          },
          "type": "url",
          "text": "https://xxxxx.com"
        },
        {
          "field": {
            "id": "k6TP9oLGgHjl",
            "type": "multiple_choice",
            "ref": "my_custom_multiple_choice2_reference"
          },
          "type": "choice",
          "choice": {
            "label": "Tokyo"
          }
        }
      ]
```

My `OrdersController.rb`

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.typeform.com/forms/XXXXXX/responses?page_size=25&query=#{current_user.hash_id}",
  headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{@token}"})
if response.code.to_i == 200
  items = response.parsed_response["items"]
  items.each do |item|
    @order = current_user.orders.find_or_create_by(landing_id: item["landing_id"]) do |order|
      item["answers"].each do |answer|
      order.landing_id = item["landing_id"]
      order.email = item["hidden"]["email"]
      order.price = item["hidden"]["price"]
      order.moduls = item["hidden"]["moduls"]
      order.project = item["hidden"]["project"]
# This is working
      order.website = answer["url"]
# This isn't working
      order.payment = answer["choice"]
    end
  end
end
```

When I change `answer["choice"]` to `answer`, I only receive the first `field` of the `ànswers`, which is `https://xxxxx.com`. If I change `answer["choice"]` to `item["answers]`, I get every `field` from the `answers`.

If I use `item["answers]["field"]["choice"]` or something similar I get this error `no implicit conversion of string into integer`.

I found the following on the Typeform documentation:

*FIELD WITH ANSWER VALUE (RELATIVE TO RESPONSE ITEM OBJECT)*

```
answers[n].choice.label
```

Probably I need to adjust my code? For me it's really unclear what this means.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `answer['url']` works since there's no "url" key on the answers.

Sounds like you want something like...

```
@order = current_user.orders.find_or_create_by(landing_id: item["landing_id"]) do |order|
  order.landing_id = item["landing_id"]
  order.email = item["hidden"]["email"]
  order.price = item["hidden"]["price"]
  order.moduls = item["hidden"]["moduls"]
  order.project = item["hidden"]["project"]

  website_field = item['answers'].select{|k,v| v['field']['type'] == 'website'}.first
  # you have an array of fields, select the first with type "website"
  order.website = website_field['text'] # now get the "text" value which is the url

  choice_field = item['answers'].select{|k,v| v['field']['type'] == 'multiple_choice'}.first
  # same but with the field with type "multiple_choice"
  order.payment = choice_field['choice']['label']
end
```